# Filenotfound exception from assets folder android?

Tags: android

While reading from file under Assets/sb/example/simple.html/It is giving filenotfound 
exception.

```
11-01 18:30:13.562: WARN/System.err(912): java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:///android_asset/sb/example/simple.html
```

Code Snippet is

```
try {
    final AssetManager assetMgr = ctx.getResources().getAssets(); 
    is = assetMgr.open(path, AssetManager.ACCESS_STREAMING);
    // is = getAssets().open(file.getAbsolutePath());
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here I had given full path of the asset folder but in assets it takes relative path.

```
 try { 
     final AssetManager assetMgr = ctx.getResources().getAssets();  
     is = assetMgr.open("sb/example/simple1.html"); 
 } catch (IOException e1) { 
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
     e1.printStackTrace(); 
 }
```

It is working....